# OpenLDAP- DirContextOperations.search((String name, String filter, SearchControls cons))

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, openldap

Need to retrieve "memberOf" attributes-used the search method but getting below error. Please suggest me the code how to retrieve.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented.
at org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter.search(DirContextAdapter.java:1055) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at com.example.authenticatingldap.WebSecurityConfig$1.mapUserFromContext(WebSecurityConfig.java:85) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:82) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
```

This the code i have written, here i need to get the member of details and set the permission/roles for the user. help would be much appreciated
//Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {``

    @Autowired
    ServerDetailsRepository serverDetailsRepository;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Value("${login_admin_role_api_list}")
    private String loginAdminRoleApiList;``

    @Value("${login_all_role_api_list}")
    private String loginAllrolesApiList;

    @Value("${login_admin_readwrite_role_api_list}")``
    private String loginAdminReadWriteRoleApiList;


    /*
     * @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     * System.out.println("inside HttpSecurity Method"); http .authorizeRequests()
     * .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() .and() .formLogin(); }
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {

        authBuilder.ldapAuthentication().
        userSearchBase("ou=people,dc=sdnlab,dc=com").
        userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
        .contextSource().root("dc=sdnlab,dc=com")
        .url("ldap://10.168.160.104:389/dc=sdnlab,dc=com");
    }

    @Bean
        public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {`
        return new LdapUserDetailsMapper() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

                Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();//receiving attributes but no memberof values
                Object[] groups2 = new Object[100];
                groups2 = ctx.getObjectAttributes("memberOf");//Null values returning

                SearchControls cons = new SearchControls();
                cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer2;

                try {
                    answer2 = ctx.search("dc=sdnlab,dc=com", String.format("(uid=%s)", username),
                            new String[] { "memberOf", "uid", "givenName", "mail", "sn" }, cons);
                    if (answer2.hasMore()) {
                        Attributes attrs = answer2.next().getAttributes();
                        System.out.println("Member of details:::" + attrs.get("memberOf").getAll());

                    } 
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Set<GrantedAuthority> authority = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
                authority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Read Only"));
                User userDetails = new User(username, "", false, false, false, false, authority);
                return userDetails;
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(loginAdminRoleApiList.split(",")).hasRole("Admin")
                .antMatchers(loginAllrolesApiList.split(",")).hasAnyRole("Read Only", "Approver", "Read Write", "Admin")
                .antMatchers(loginAdminReadWriteRoleApiList.split(",")).hasAnyRole("Admin", "Read Write")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

Comment: Have tried String[] memberOfs = ctx.getStringAttributes("memberOf"); but didn't help

Comment: /*
 * 
 * Search Query in the LDAP:
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b  "uid=praveen,ou=people,dc=sdnlab,dc=com" dn memberof
output :
dn: uid=praveen,ou=people,dc=sdnlab,dc=com
memberOf: cn=tafadmin,ou=groups,dc=sdnlab,dc=com
 */

Comment: Suggest me where am i going wrong? why i couldn't ?

Comment: Are you sure there *are* any `memberOf` atttributes? `memberOf` is an operational attribute. You don't get it unless you ask for it specifically, or ask for all operational attributes with `"+"`. NB `Object[] groups2 = new Object[100];`: you don't need to initialize a variable when you assign it in the very next line.

Answer (score -1):

You can set search filter for Member of as below

```
StringBuilder searchFilter = new StringBuilder(
                "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=");
        searchFilter.append(ldapGroup).append(",OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=nos,DC=abc,DC=com))"); // nos.abc.com
        
        BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(ctxSrc);
        authenticator.setUserSearch(new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("", searchFilter.toString(), ctxSrc));
        authenticator.afterPropertiesSet();

        Authentication authenticationObj = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        DirContextOperations user = authenticator.authenticate(authenticationObj);
```

Then you can get user attributes

```
 LOG.debug("UID string: " + user.getAttributes());
```

Comment: I have edited the query and pasted the code which am using, can you please suggest me why this searh method not working

Comment: This will not retrieve `memberOf` or any other operational attribute. You haven't tried this.